# What is the cost of querying BigQuery REST APIs. Specifically: projects.locations.searchLinks

Tags: google-bigquery, google-bigquery-java

I'm trying to use the searchLinks API provided by Google BigQuery, but they have no information on how much it costs.

Looking for any pointers on how to think about the cost for using the API. API reference:
https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/data-lineage/rest/v1/projects.locations/searchLinks

I would appreciate any pointers!

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dataplex/pricing#data-catalog-api-pricing

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a community wiki:

As what Mikhail referenced,  the first 1M api calls in a month is free. Over than that, you get charged 10 usd per 100k api calls